# Making a class method recognize which class context it's running in

Tags: python

I need to refactor existing code by collapsing a method that's copy-and-pasted between various classed that inherit from one another into a single method. 
So I produced the following code:

```
class A(object):
    def rec(self):
        return 1

class B(A):
    def rec(self):
        return self.rec_gen(B)

    def rec_gen(self, rec_class):
        return super(rec_class, self).rec() + 1

class C(B):
    def rec(self):
        return self.rec_gen(C)

if __name__=='__main__':
    b = B(); c = C()
    print c.rec()
    print b.rec()
```

And the output:

```
3
2
```

What still bothers me is that in the 'rec' method I need to tell 'rec_gen' the context of the class in which it's running. Is there a way for 'rec_gen' to figure it out by itself in runtime?

Comment: Not really sure what your trying to do, but I believe you can get the class from self.\_\_class\_\_

Comment: @monkut, this is not possible, because self.__class__ always has the calling class, so if I call c.rec(), self.__class__.__name__ will always be 'C'

Comment: @monkut Doing that is likely to lead to infinite recursion - self.__class__ is always the actual class of the object, not the class where the method you're currently in was defined.

Comment: `self.__class__`  is all you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This capability has been added to Python 3 - see [PEP 3135](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/). In a nutshell:

```
class B(A):
    def rec(self):
        return super().rec() + 1
```

I think you've created the convoluted `rec()`/`rec_gen()` setup because you couldn't automatically find the class, but in case you want that anyway the following should work:

```
class A(object):
    def rec(self):
        return 1

class B(A):
    def rec(self):
        # __class__ is a cell that is only created if super() is in the method
        super()
        return self.rec_gen(__class__)

    def rec_gen(self, rec_class):
        return super(rec_class, self).rec() + 1

class C(B):
    def rec(self):
        # __class__ is a cell that is only created if super() is in the method
        super()
        return self.rec_gen(__class__)
```

The simplest solution in Python 2 is to use a private member to hold the `super` object:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__super = super(B)

    def rec(self):
        return self.__super.rec() + 1
```

But that still suffers from the need to specify the actual class in one place, and if you happen to have two identically-named classes in the class hierarchy (e.g. from different modules) this method will break.

There were a couple of us who made recipes for automatic resolution for Python 2 prior to the existence of PEP 3135 - my method is at [self.super on ActiveState](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/286195/). Basically, it allows the following:

```
class B(A, autosuper):
    def rec(self):
        return self.super().rec() + 1
```

or in the case that you're calling a parent method with the same name (the most common case):

```
class B(A, autosuper):
    def rec(self):
        return self.super() + 1
```

Caveats to this method:

1. It's quite slow. I have a version sitting around somewhere that does bytecode manipulation to improve the speed a lot.
2. It's not consistent with PEP 3135 (although it was a proposal for the Python 3 super at one stage).
3. It's quite complex.
4. It's a mix-in base class.

I don't know if the above would enable you to meet your requirements. With a small change to the recipe though you could find out what class you're in and pass that to `rec_gen()` - basically extract the class-finding code out of `_getSuper()` into its own method.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution for python 2.x would be to use a metaclass to automatically define the `rec` method in all your subclasses:

```
class RecGen(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        new_cls = super(RecGen, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

        if bases != (object,):
            def rec(self):
                return super(new_cls, self).rec() + 1
            new_cls.rec = rec

        return new_cls

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = RecGen
    def rec(self):
        return 1

class B(A):
    pass

class C(B):
    pass
```

Note that if you're just trying to get something like the number of parent classes, it would be easier to use `self.__class__.__mro__` directly:

```
class A(object):
    def rec(self):
        return len(self.__class__.__mro__)-1

class B(A):
    pass

class C(B):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but if it is just to have a method that returns a different constant value for each class then use class attributes to store the value. It isn't clear at all from your example that you need to go anywhere near `super()`.

```
class A(object):
    REC = 1
    def rec(self):
        return self.REC

class B(A):
    REC = 2

class C(B):
    REC = 3

if __name__=='__main__':
    b = B(); c = C()
    print c.rec()
    print b.rec()
```